# NestJs validation pipe not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs

I have the following DTO class in my project:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from "class-validator";

export class CreateDomainDTO {

  @IsString()
  codigo_website: string;

  @IsString()
  website_name: string

}
```

I have NestJs default validation pipe applied for my entire project:
[main.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peVc9.png)

However, NestJs is messing up the validation and returning a response that doesn't make sense to me.

When I send this payload in my request:

```
{
    "codigo_website": "lipgMEjz4altEmeb9hms",
    "website_name": "Modelo 2.1"
}
```

I get the following validation error:

```
"property {\"codigo_website\":\"lipgMEjz4altEmeb9hms\",\"website_name\":\"Modelo 2.1\"} should not exist","codigo_website must be a string","website_name must be a string"
```

It is considering my entire body as being a single property and I don't have any idea why. Plus, this error seems to only happen in production, but within a few days ago it was working fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Should I create a custom validation pipe?

Grateful in advance.

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." [ask] Can you provide the request headers and the body.

Comment: How do you send the request? What's the `Content-Type`? It looks like the payload isn't getting deserialized

Comment: Here's a part of my headers.



Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 69
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: lipsum.lipsum.com

I think the error is being caused by the Content-Type header as @JayMcDoniel mentioned above. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on postman, make sure the body is raw and select JSON. If using frontend API, set the content-type to `application/json`.

[image]